# In WPF, how to pass a parameter to ICommand.CanExecute()

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public bool SelectAll
    {
        get { return this.Get<bool>("SelectAll"); }
        set 
        {
            this.Set<bool>("SelectAll", value);
            if (this.SelectAllCommand.CanExecute(null))
                this.SelectAllCommand.Execute(value);
        }
    }
```

As my code, I want to a checkbox - select all function.
When I manually click the "select all", I want to execute the SelectAllCommand, but if the checkbox is selected automtically, the CanExecute should return false to me....

I don't how to pass a parameter to CanExecute... How can I perfectly do that ...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not bind to `CheckBox.Command` and `CheckBox.CommandParameter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your code, you're currently passing a parameter, that parameter just happens to be null. So don't you more accurately want to do

```
if (this.SelectAllCommand.CanExecute(value))
```

?

Comment: yes, I know, but I have to declare a variable, e.g. bool isAuto to control ? and then pass the variable to CanExecute() ? is that a good code style ... ? thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps some more explanation would be helpful.